# Does a 32-bit Linux program's entire runtime lib tree need to be 32-bit?

Tags: linux, 32bit-64bit, libraries

On my 64-bit RHEL machine, I'm compiling and running a C & Fortran program that is 32-bit only.  It invokes the non-static version of a lot of standard Linux libs (X11, OpenGL/Mesa, Motif, etc...), which of course invoke other libs (libjpeg, libc, etc).  Do I have to install the 32-bit versions of that entire devl lib tree in order to build this program validly?  And do I have to install the 32-bit versions of that entire run-time lib tree in order to run it without it segfaulting or whatever?

Comment: A missing library isn't going to cause a segfault. The program will just refuse to run if a library is missing and tell you what is missing. If the programs and libraries are properly packaged the package manager should be able to install everything you need.

Comment: This program is not package-managed. Also, I'm worried about: 1) name-colliding 64-bit libs, and 2) late run-time-loaded libs

Comment: The libraries are supposed to be installed by the package manager. The 32 and 64 bit versions of the libraries will be installed in different directories. I have only tested that on Ubuntu though, never RHEL.

Comment: Yes, but the 64- and 32-bit libs have the same filenames (not including dir), and I don't know any way to tell the linker or the program not to fall back on e.g. /lib64/ if it fails to find a lib in /lib/ .

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you need 32-bit versions of the libraries, since the binaries are compiled as 32-bit versions, which assume 32-bit memory model on the libraries too.